# How to rename a bluetooth controller connected to AppleTV

Tags: appletv

Is is possible to rename a bluetooth device in AppleTV? I have two NIMBUS controllers which are named with the same default name and I would like to have two distinct names to recognise which one is currently connected.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you can rename the device on tvOS. If you are able to pair the Nimbus with an iOS device, I can confirm this works and the renamed device appears on iOS and tvOS.

Unfortunately, renaming the device on macOS does not seem to have any effect.